# Reading/Changing pixels of 3D shapes in Processing

Tags: 3d, processing, pixel

Dear collected wisdom,

I am trying to recreate with Processing the following image:
[image: my goal]

Pretty much I need to create two half cubes, whose outlines should be bolder, as long as they are "visually located within" the boundaries set by the grey square in the background.

So far I have managed to achieve most of the target picture, however I cannot find a way to read the respective pixels that need to become darker. This is where I am now visually (the difference in rotation of the cubes is of no significance at the moment):
[image: what I did so far]

And this is my code:

```java
PGraphics pg1;
PGraphics pg2;

void setup() {
  size(400,400,P3D);
  background(255);

  pg1 = createGraphics(200,400,P3D);
  pg2 = createGraphics(200,400,P3D);

  loadPixels();
  for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      color grey = color(230);
      if (x > 99 && x < 300 && y > 99 && y < 300) { 
        pixels[y*width+x] = grey;
      }
    }
  }
  updatePixels();
}

void draw() {
  pg1.beginDraw(); 
    //left cube
    pg1.pushMatrix();
    pg1.ortho();
    pg1.translate(200,200,0);
    pg1.rotateX(-2.5289822);
    pg1.rotateY(-2.8117256);
    pg1.rotateZ(2.9670599);
    pg1.stroke(0,10);
    pg1.strokeWeight(0.5);
    pg1.noFill();
    pg1.box(200);
    pg1.popMatrix();

    //vertical line
    pg1.translate(200,200,0);
    pg1.stroke(230);
    pg1.strokeWeight(0.5);
    pg1.line(0,-200,0,0,200,0); 
  pg1.endDraw();

  pg2.beginDraw(); 
    //right cube
    pg2.pushMatrix();
    pg2.ortho();
    pg2.translate(0,200,0);
    pg2.rotateX(-1.24);
    pg2.rotateY(-2.0);
    pg2.rotateZ(-2.9670599);
    pg2.stroke(0,10);
    pg2.strokeWeight(0.5);
    pg2.noFill();
    pg2.box(200);
    pg2.popMatrix();

    //vertical line
    pg2.translate(0,200,0);
    pg2.stroke(230);
    pg2.strokeWeight(0.5);
    pg2.line(0,-200,0,0,200,0);
  pg2.endDraw();

  //display pgs
  image(pg1, 0, 0); 
  image(pg2, 200, 0);

  //how can I change specific pixels of the box outlines??
  loadPixels();
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
     for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
       if (x > 99 && x < 300 && y > 99 && y < 300) { 
         float r = red(pixels[y*width+x]);
         float g = green(pixels[y*width+x]);
         float b = blue(pixels[y*width+x]);
         pixels[y*width+x] =  color(r,g,b,255);
       }
     }
    }
    updatePixels();  
}
```

I have been trying various versions of changing the stroke weight based on pixel location or by changing the alpha value of the stroke color (before or after drawing the cubes), but apparently I am doing something wrong. I am not also sure, if this is anyway possible, as I am apparently(?) trying to read a 2D image from a 3D shape..

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks a lot - Ilias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pixels can be tedious for this task, especially since you need to draw thicker lines in certain areas.

I recommend using two more PGraphics that render almost the same content as your existing two, but with a thicker stroke.

You can then [copy()](https://processing.org/reference/copy_.html) or [blend()](https://processing.org/reference/blend_.html) pixels from the PGraphics using thicker outlines on top of your code.

It's usually a good idea to group instructions that are re-used into functions. Here's a tweaked version of your code using an extra function and two PGraphics layers:

```
PGraphics pg1;
PGraphics pg2;
PGraphics pg3;
PGraphics pg4;

void setup() {
  size(400,400,P3D);
  background(255);
  noStroke();
  fill(0,32);

  pg1 = createGraphics(200,400,P3D);
  pg2 = createGraphics(200,400,P3D);
  pg3 = createGraphics(200,400,P3D);
  pg4 = createGraphics(200,400,P3D);

  box(pg1,200,200,0,//pg,x,y,z
          -2.5289822,-2.8117256,2.9670599,//rx,ry,rz
          0,1.5,200);//stroke,thickness,boxSize
  box(pg2,0  ,200,0,
         -1.24,-2.0,-2.9670599,
         127,1.5,200);
  //same as above, just using thicker strokes
  box(pg3,200,200,0,
         -2.5289822,-2.8117256,2.9670599,
          0,3.5,200);
  box(pg4,0  ,200,0,
         -1.24,-2.0,-2.9670599,
         64,3.5,200);

  //display pgs
  image(pg1, 0, 0); 
  image(pg2, 200, 0);
  //copy pixels from pgs drawn with thicker lines
  copy(pg3, 100, 100, 100, 200, 
            100, 100, 100, 200);
  copy(pg4, 0  , 100, 100, 200, 
            200, 100, 100, 200);
  //overlay transparent rectangle on top
  rect(100,100,200,200);
}

void draw() {

}
//render a box in a given PGraphics with options for position, rotation, stroke and size
void box(PGraphics pg,
         float x,float y,float z,
         float rx,float ry,float rz,
         int cubeStroke,float cubeStrokeWeight,float cubeSize){
  pg.beginDraw(); 
    //left cube
    pg.pushMatrix();
    pg.ortho();
    pg.translate(x,y,z);
    pg.rotateX(rx);
    pg.rotateY(ry);
    pg.rotateZ(rz);
    pg.stroke(cubeStroke);
    pg.strokeWeight(cubeStrokeWeight);
    pg.noFill();
    pg.box(cubeSize);
    pg.popMatrix();

    //vertical line
    pg.translate(200,200,0);
    pg.stroke(230);
    pg.strokeWeight(0.5);
    pg.line(0,-200,0,0,200,0); 
  pg.endDraw();
}
```

Hopefully the spacing makes it easier to follow the many arguments.
Here's a peview:

[image: Manfred Mohr Cube study Processing port test]

So...

[image: clippy]

You should check out the wealth of resources on [Golan Levin's courses](http://golancourses.net/), for example related to [Manfred Mohr](http://cmuems.com/2013/a/?s=manfred%20mohr). Additionally check out the [ReCode Project](http://recodeproject.com/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, man, for making this clear! It helped a lot! Yes, you guessed right, I am working on Manfred Mohr, and the links you provided are really great! Thanks again.

Comment: Glad it helped. You probably should also check out the works of Frieder Nake :)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for an **erode filter**.

You can use the [`filter()`](https://www.processing.org/reference/filter_.html) function to apply a filter to that section of your image. Processing comes with a few predefined filters, and the erode function does exactly what you're describing.

Consider this code:

```java
void setup(){
  size(200, 200);
}

void draw(){
  background(255);
  line(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

Which generates this:

[image]

You can apply an erode filter:

```java
void setup(){
  size(200, 200);
}

void draw(){
  background(255);
  line(0, 0, width, height);
  filter(ERODE);
}
```

Which brings out the black line:

[image]

You can apply different filters, or the same filter multiple times, to achieve your desired effect:

```java
void setup(){
  size(200, 200);
}

void draw(){
  background(255);
  line(0, 0, width, height);
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    filter(ERODE);
  }
}
```

[image]

Note that you can also apply the `filter()` function to instances of `PGraphics`, which is what you'll want to do.

Comment: Hi, Kevin, and thanks for your comment! I have tried using filter() but still I cannot see how I can apply it to the *specific sections/pixels* of the boxes (as shown in my picture). Any advice on this?

Comment: @IliasKyriazis You wouldn't need to get specific pixels. Just copy the pixels you want to make bold into a `PGraphics`, call `filter()` on the `PGraphics`, and then draw that back to the screen.

Comment: I see what you mean, Kevin! Basically similar approach to George's answer but with filter(). Thanks a lot!!